# Connection refused when using Rack Proxy

Tags: ruby, proxy, rack

I'm trying to catch all `*.dev` requests on port 80 and send them to the right Rack project by using [Rack Proxy](https://github.com/ncr/rack-proxy). I'm able to catch the requests and based on the URI I'll look for a `config.ru` in a specific folder. When I'm able to find one I'll boot up the server on port 3000.

After that, whenever I recieve a request on port 80, I try to set the `HTTP_HOST` to `localhost:3000`, but I'm getting the message `Unexpected error while processing request: Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 3000`. I am able to access the application through `localhost:3000`, but not through a `*.dev` domain. I already tried using different ports, but that's not working either, so I guess it has something to do with the user that's running it. However, I hope someone can help me with this.

```ruby
require 'rack-proxy'

class AppProxy < Rack::Proxy
  def rewrite_env(env)
    request = Rack::Request.new(env)
    site = request.host[0..-5]
    uid = File.stat(__FILE__).uid

    path = Etc.getpwuid(uid).dir + '/Software/Applications/'

    front_controller = "#{path}#{site}/config.ru"
    if File.file?(front_controller)

     system "rackup -p 3000 -D #{front_controller} "
     env["HTTP_HOST"] = "localhost:3000"
   else
    raise Exception.new "Not found"
   end

  env
 end
end

run AppProxy.new
```

**EDIT**: I've checked if there is something listening on port 3000. After running the server and `sudo lsof -i -n -P | grep TCP` I get the following result for the ports 80 and 3000:

```
ruby      56247           root   10u  IPv4 0x727d74bd0b95bd9b      0t0       TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
ruby      56247           root   11u  IPv4 0x727d74bd0a3b9bfb      0t0    TCP 127.0.0.1:80->127.0.0.1:52773 (ESTABLISHED)
ruby      56255           root   12u  IPv6 0x727d74bd094e3c8b      0t0    TCP [::1]:3000 (LISTEN)
```

I'm not sure if this is any useful because I don't know the exact meaning of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved it**. The problem was that booting up the server was a bit slower then setting the HTTP_HOST to a different location and port 3000 was not in use yet. Waiting for a second solved the problem. My code looks like this now:

```
require 'rack-proxy'

class AppProxy < Rack::Proxy
  def rewrite_env(env)
    request = Rack::Request.new(env)
    site = request.host[0..-5]
    uid = File.stat(__FILE__).uid

    path = Etc.getpwuid(uid).dir + '/Software/Applications/'
    front_controller = "#{path}#{site}/config.ru"

    if File.file?(front_controller)
       system "rackup -D -p 3000 #{front_controller} "

       sleep(1)

       env["HTTP_HOST"] = "localhost:3000"
    else
       raise Exception.new "Not found"
    end

    env
  end
 end

run AppProxy.new
```